# Calculator Dependency Tree Python (sympy / numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I would like to have users enter specific values and then the system computes numerous results based on what these - My program is getting very complicated with just a few functions. I have included an example with 3 simple functions and 6 variables with the following relationships:

[image]

The Code I have is as follows:

```
class MyCalculator:
def __init__(self):
    self.a = None
    self.b = None
    self.c = None
    self.d = None
    self.e = None
    self.f = None

def set(self, field, val):
    if field == "a": self.a = val
    if field == "b": self.b = val
    if field == "c": self.c = val
    if field == "d": self.d = val
    if field == "e": self.e = val

    for i in range(10):  # circle round a few times to ensure everything has computed
        if self.a and self.b:
            self.c = self.a * self.b

        if self.a and self.c:
            self.b = self.c / self.a

        if self.b and self.c:
            self.a = self.c / self.b

        if self.b and self.d:
            self.e = self.b + self.d

        if self.e and self.b:
            self.d = self.e - self.b

        if self.e and self.d:
            self.b = self.e - self.d

        if self.c and self.e:
            self.f = self.c / self.e

        if self.f and self.e:
            self.e = self.f * self.e

        if self.f and self.c:
            self.e = self.c / self.f

def status(self):
    print(f"a = {self.a} b = {self.b} c = {self.c} d = {self.d} e = {self.e} f = {self.f} ")
```

Then If i run the following code:

```
example1 = MyCalculator()
example1.set("a", 5)
example1.set("e", 7)
example1.set("c", 2)
example1.status()
```

This will print out a = 5.0 b = 0.40000000000000036 c = 2.0000000000000018 d = 6.6 e = 7.0 f = 0.285714285714286

I would like a much simpler way to achieve the same result using something like sympy and numpy but so far I cant find anything that will work

Comment: Don't use `if val` to test if your numerical placeholders are non-none; it will ovelook cases where `val = 0`. Rather use `if val is not None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's a live version of this solution online you can try for yourself](https://repl.it/@telamonian/calculatedependentexpressions)

Here's a complete solution that uses Sympy. All you need to do is enter your desired expressions in the `exprStr` tuple at the top of the `MyCalculator` definition, and then all of the dependency satisfaction stuff should take care of itself:

```
from sympy import S, solveset, Symbol
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

class MyCalculator:
    # sympy assumes all expressions are set equal to zero
    exprStr = (
        'a*b - c',
        'b + d - e',
        'c/e - f'
    )
    # parse the expression strings into actual expressions
    expr = tuple(parse_expr(es) for es in exprStr)

    # create a dictionary to lookup expressions based on the symbols they depend on
    exprDep = {}
    for e in expr:
        for s in e.free_symbols:
            exprDep.setdefault(s, set()).add(e)

    # create a set of the used symbols for input validation
    validSymb = set(exprDep.keys())

    def __init__(self, usefloat=False):
        """usefloat: if set, store values as standard Python floats (instead of the Sympy numeric types)
        """
        self.vals = {}
        self.numify = float if usefloat else lambda x: x

    def set(self, symb, val, _exclude=None):
        # ensure that symb is a sympy Symbol object
        if isinstance(symb, str): symb = Symbol(symb)
        if symb not in self.validSymb:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input symbol.\n"
                             "symb: %s, validSymb: %s" % (symb, self.validSymb))

        # initialize the set of excluded expressions, if needed
        if _exclude is None: _exclude = set()

        # record the updated value of symb
        self.vals[symb] = self.numify(val)
        # loop over all of the expressions that depend on symb
        for e in self.exprDep[symb]:
            if e in _exclude:
                # we've already calculated an update for e in an earlier recursion, skip it
                continue
            # mark that e should be skipped in future recursions
            _exclude.add(e)

            # determine the symbol and value of the next update (if any)
            nextsymbval = self.calc(symb, e)
            if nextsymbval is not None:
                # there is another symbol to update, recursively call self.set
                self.set(*nextsymbval, _exclude)

    def calc(self, symb, e):
        # find knowns and unknowns of the expression
        known = [s for s in e.free_symbols if s in self.vals]
        unknown = [s for s in e.free_symbols if s not in known]

        if len(unknown) > 1:
            # too many unknowns, can't do anything with this expression right now
            return None
        elif len(unknown) == 1:
            # solve for the single unknown
            nextsymb = unknown[0]
        else:
            # solve for the first known that isn't the symbol that was just changed
            nextsymb = known[0] if known[0] != symb else known[1]

        # do the actual solving
        sol = solveset(e, nextsymb, domain=S.Reals)

        # evaluate the solution given the known values, then return a tuple of (next-symbol, result)
        return nextsymb, sol.subs(self.vals).args[0]

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(sorted('{} = {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in self.vals.items()))
```

Testing it out:

```
mycalc = MyCalculator()
mycalc.set("a", 5)
mycalc.set("e", 7)
mycalc.set("c", 2)
print(mycalc)
```

Output:

```
a = 5 b = 2/5 c = 2 d = 33/5 e = 7 f = 2/7
```

One of the neat things about Sympy is that it uses rational math, which avoids any weird rounding errors in, for example, `2/7`. If you'd prefer to get your results as standard Python `float` values, you can pass the `usefloat` flag to `MyCalculator`:

```
mycalc = MyCalculator(usefloat=True)
mycalc.set("a", 5)
mycalc.set("e", 7)
mycalc.set("c", 2)
print(mycalc)
```

Output:

```
a = 5.0 b = 0.4 c = 2.0 d = 6.6 e = 7.0 f = 0.2857142857142857
```

Comment: That is brilliant thanks so much! How complicated can the string expressions be? Can I call a function from it eg 'Myfunc(a,b,c)' where i can implement a more complex computation on variables a,b and c?

Comment: What you want can be done, but there are some tricks to doing it correctly. Since it requires a separate discussion, you should ask a separate question about it (maybe something along the lines of "How do you use user-defined functions in Sympy string expressions?").

Answer (score 0):

```
In [107]: a=2.
In [108]: a=5.
In [109]: b=0.4
In [110]: c=lambda: a*b
In [111]: d=6.6
In [112]: e=lambda: b+d
In [113]: f=lambda: c()/e()
In [114]: print(a,b,c(), d, e(), f())
          5.0 0.4 2.0 6.6 7.0 0.2857142857142857
```

You can probably capture the above logic in a class.
It would be possible to hold 'variables' as _a, _b and _d.  Then a(), b() and d() could be functions that return _a etc...
More a pointer than a whole answer but it may help.

Using a structure like that below it would be possible to create a situation where you always call a function and not need to know when to use a and c() but always use a() and c().

```
In [121]: def var(init=0.0):
     ...:     def func(v=None):
     ...:         nonlocal init
     ...:         if v==None: return init
     ...:         init=v
     ...:     return func
     ...:

In [122]: a=var(100.)

In [123]: a()
Out[123]: 100.0

In [124]: a(25.)

In [125]: a()
Out[125]: 25.0
```